# On what factors does the download speed of assets from Amazon S3 depends?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, data-transfer

How fast can we download files from Amazon S3, is there an upper limit (and they distribute it between all the requests from the same user), or does it only depend on my internet connection download speed? I couldn't find it in their SLA.

What other factors does it depend on? Do they throttle the data transfer rate at some level to prevent abuse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been addressed in the recent [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) team post [Amazon S3 Performance Tips & Tricks](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/03/amazon-s3-performance-tips-tricks-seattle-hiring-event.html):

> **First: for smaller workloads (<50 total requests per second), none of
>   the below applies, no matter how many total objects one has!** S3 has a
>   bunch of automated agents that work behind the scenes, smoothing out
>   load all over the system, to ensure the myriad diverse workloads all
>   share the resources of S3 fairly and snappily. Even workloads that
>   burst occasionally up over 100 requests per second really don't need
>   to give us any hints about what's coming...**we are designed to just
>   grow and support these workloads forever.** S3 is a true scale-out
>   design in action.
>
> **S3 scales to both short-term and long-term workloads far, far greater
>   than this. We have  customers continuously performing thousands of
>   requests per second against S3, all day every day.** [...] We worked with other
>   customers through our Premium Developer Support offerings to help them
>   design a system that would scale basically indefinitely on S3. Today
>   we’re going to publish that guidance for everyone’s benefit.
>
> *[emphasis mine]*

You may want to read the entire post to gain more insight into the S3 architecture and resulting challenges for really *massive workloads* (i.e., as stressed by the S3 team, it won't apply at all for most use cases).

Comment: Scalability has little relation to speed. Amazon S3 could be able to serve hundreds of thousands of simultaneous requests per second yet each request could be served very slowly. And your visitors don't see nor do they care how scalable your site is. All they care is how fast pages are being loaded and shown to them.